# Does there exist a function such that $f(a)f(b)=f(a^2b^2)?$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Given $S=\{2,3,4,5,6,7,\cdots,n,\cdots,\} = \Bbb N_{>1}$, prove whether there exists a function $f:S\to S$, such that for any positive $a,b$:
>   $$f(a)f(b)=f(a^2b^2),a\neq b?$$

This is 2015 APMO problem 2 (this event ended yesterday: see [APMO](http://www.amt.edu.au/event/asian-pacific-mathematical-olympiad-apmo/)), maybe I think didn't exist such a function, but I can't prove it.

---

My attempt:

Consider $p_{i}$ is $i^{th}$ prime,such $f(2)=2^2,f(3)=5^2,f(5)=11^2,\cdots?$

Comment: $f(a)f(b)f(c)=f(a^4b^4c^2)=f(a^4b^2c^4)=f(a^2b^4c^4)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$f(a^6)f(a^5)f(a^3)f(a^2)f(a)=f(a^{22})f(a^3)f(a^2)f(a)\\
=f(a^{50})f(a^2)f(a)\\=f(a^{104})f(a)\\
=f(a^6)f(a^5)f(a^3)f(a^2)f(a)=f(a^6)f(a^5)f(a^3)f(a^6)\\
=f(a^6)f(a^5)f(a^{18})\\
=f(a^6)f(a^{46})=f(a^{104})$$

Comment: Try to find a solution that starts with four factors instead of five.  I think there is one.

Comment: @Michael: Following your answer, I find that there can be infinitely many solutions that starts with four factors. e.g. $f(a^{10})f(a^5)f(a^2)f(a) = f(a^{64})f(a)$, whereas $f(a)f(a^2)f(a^5)f(a^{10}) = f(a^{64})$. Another example is $f(a^{10})f(a^3)f(a^2)f(a) = f(a^{56})f(a)$, whereas $f(a)f(a^2)f(a^3)f(a^{10}) = f(a^{56})$.

Comment: Nice,Now I consider simaler and more hard problem,there exsit $f:S\to S$,and such $f(a)f(b)=f((ab)^3)$?

Comment: @NewZealand: The answer is still no. Using the same way to tackle the problem, $f(a^{21})f(a^{10})f(a^3)f(a^2) = f(a^{93})f(a^3)f(a^2) = f(a^{288})f(a^2)$, while $f(a^2)f(a^3)f(a^{10})f(a^{21}) = f(a^{15})f(a^{10})f(a^{21}) = f(a^{75})f(a^{21}) = f(a^{288})$.

Comment: In general, for $f(a)f(b) = f(a^2b^2), a \ne b$, the function $f: S \rightarrow S$ does not exist. To find a counter example, consider $f(a^{x_1})f(a^{x_2})f(a^{x_3})f(a^{x_4}) = f(a^y)f(a^{x_4})$ while $f(a^{x_4})f(a^{x_3})f(a^{x_2})f(a^{x_1}) = f(a^y)$. This is true when $x_1 = 3x_3 + 4x_4$ and all $x_i$ are different positive integers. Similarly, for $f(a)f(b) = f(a^3b^3), a \ne b$, the function $f: S \rightarrow S$ does not exist. This is true when $2x_1 = 8x_3 + 9x_4$ and all $x_i$ are different positive integers.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer by Michael is a nice first proof, but I feel it's quite a *deus ex machina*.

Therefore, let me sketch an approach to solve the general situation, providing more insight.

---

So suppose that for all $a \ne b$, we have: $$f(a^nb^n) = f(a)f(b)$$

Then in particular, for all $a,b,c,d$, $a \ne b,c \ne d$:

$$a^nb^n = c^nd^n \implies f(a)f(b) = f(c)f(d)$$

Rewriting and using that $n$th powers are injective on the natural numbers:

$$\frac ac = \frac db \leadsto ab = cd \leadsto f(a)f(b) = f(c)f(d) \leadsto \frac{f(a)}{f(c)} = \frac{f(d)}{f(b)}$$

In particular, for any $x,y \ge 2$:

$$\frac{ax}x = \frac{ay}y \leadsto \frac{f(ax)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(ay)}{f(y)}$$

That is, there exists some $\lambda_a$ such that for all $x$, $f(ax) = \lambda_a f(x)$.

Because $a,x,y$ were completely arbitrary, we can derive inductively from $$f(aa^n) = \lambda_a f(a^n) = \lambda_{a^n}f(a)$$ that $\lambda_{a^n} = \lambda_a^n$. From here on, we can apply the following basic algebra:

\begin{align*}
f(a^{3n}) &= \lambda_a^{3n-1} f(a) = f(a)f(a^2) = \lambda_a f(a)^2 \leadsto f(a) = \lambda_a^{3n-2}\\
f(a^{4n}) &= \lambda_a^{4n-1} f(a) = f(a)f(a^3) = \lambda_a^2 f(a)^2 \leadsto f(a) = \lambda_a^{4n-3}
\end{align*}
Hence, $\lambda_a^{n-1} = \frac{f(a)}{f(a)} = 1$, and we conclude that:

$$f(a) = \lambda_a^{3n-2} = \lambda_a (\lambda_a^{n-1})^3 = \lambda_a$$

which contradicts that $f(a) \in \Bbb N_{>1}$. Therefore, such an $f$ cannot exist.

---

I came to this approach by writing down the conditions on values of the form $f(a^2b^2)$ and recognising that this was reminiscent of the construction of the rational numbers.

Answer (score -3):

Let $f:S\mapsto S $ be $ f(x)=y$ where $y$ is the smallest number in $S$ so that $y^k=x$ with $k\in\{1,2,3...\}. $ This function "drops" exponents.
It would work like this $f(36)=f(216)=f(6)=6$

Suppose $a=c^d$ and $b=e^f$ where $c\neq h^i,  e\neq j^k $with $h,j \in S$ and $i,k \in \{1,2,3...\}$ $. Let $g=gcd(d,f)$

Then $f(a^2b^2)=f((ab)^2)=f(ab)=f(c^de^f)=f((c^\frac{d}{g}d^\frac{f}{g})^g)=f(c^\frac{d}{g}d^\frac{f}{g})=c^\frac{d}{g}d^\frac{f}{g}$

$=f(c^{\frac{d}{g} g})f(d^{\frac{f}{g}g})=f(c^d)f(d^f)=f(a)f(b)$

showing that the function has the desired property.

Comment: This doesn't work - if $a$ and $b$ have a factor in common (say $a=45$, $b=12$) then $f(a)f(b)$ will have that common factor 'twice' whereas $f(a^2b^2)$ will only have it once.  (here, for instance, $f(a)f(b) = f(3^25)f(2^23) = 15\cdot6=90$ while $f(a^2b^2)=f(3^45^22^43^2)=2\cdot3\cdot5=30$.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ (at the beginning) is incomplete (you say that $f(x^k)=f(x)$ but give no precision on $f(x)$) and you don't prove that such a definition is non-ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, now I see, my definition was not clear (thank you!), I eddited a bit, $f(45)=45$ and $f(12)=12$, but $f(16)=2$

Comment: $f(45)*f(12)=45*12=f(45*12)=f((45*12)^2)=f(45^2*12^2)$

Comment: Never mind, now I see it does not work regardless because of the common factors, I should get more sleep before doing math XD

Comment: The counterexample would be $f(6)f(36)=6*6=16$ but $f(6^2*36^2)=f(6^5)=6$